# shortcodes/tags in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I m looking for function where user can add **[name]** shortcode in textarea content box. so un executing it will replace the shortcode with fetched data from the database i.e **John Doe**.

[name] = John Doe

[email] = johny@gmail.com

[phone] = 9876543210

Suppose user type source code as `<p>my name is [name]</p>`.

so on submitting the page shortcode should be replaced with `<p>my name is John Doe</p>`.

I tried below code but it's of long shortcode which open/close and inbetween content which will be difficult to remember to client.

```html
$text = "My example text [shortcode_name]content of shortcode[/shortcode_name] is cool.";
$text = "My example text [shortcode_xyz]content of shortcode[/shortcode_name] is cool.";
$bhaku = "ss";

$pattern= '/\[(shortcode_name)\](.|\s)*?\[\/\1\]/'; 
echo preg_replace($pattern,$bhaku ,$text);
```

Comment: Don't you just need to use `str_replace` in that instance? That is if you simply want to replace `[shortcode]` and not `[shortcode]Foo bar[/shortcode]`

Answer (score 0):

You will need ajax to request data from database without reloading the page.

You can also use [Ajax jquery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

```
$('#MyForm').ajaxForm(function(response){
    //Print response
    $('#ResAreaId').html(response);
});
```

Comment: It's a PHP/MySQL question so I would assume it's all being done at the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use regular expresssion if you only want to replace a shortcode like `[name]` with a name from a database or array. You could instead use str_replace:

```
$text = "<p>My name is [name], my phone is [phone] and my email is [email]</p>";        

$db = array('[name]'=>'John Doe', 
            '[email]'=>'johny@gmail.com', 
            '[phone]'=>'9876543210'
            );

echo str_replace(array_keys($db), array_values($db), $text);
```

Try it yourself: https://eval.in/742786

And if you instead in another scenario would want to replace the input between two tags, you could use regular expressions like this example:

```
$text = "<p>My name is [name]Jenny[/name], and my phone is [phone]1234567[/phone], and mail: [email]mail@mail.com[/email]</p>";                 

$tags = array('name', 'email', 'phone'); // TAGS TO FETCH INPUT FROM

$input = array(); // ARRAY WITH EXTRACTED INPUT

foreach ($tags as $tag){ // LOOP THROUGH EACH TAG
    $pattern = "/\[$tag ?.*\](.*)\[\/$tag\]/";
    preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
    $input[$tag] = isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] :''; //GET VALUE IF THE TAG EXISTS IN TEXT, ELSE RETURN EMPTY STRING
}               

print_r($input);
```

Should give this result:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Jenny
    [email] => mail@mail.com
    [phone] => 1234567
)
```

Try it: https://eval.in/742788